# Verbs in the simple present vs. perfect present

Tags: usage, present-tense, perfect-aspect

Please help me and tell me, which one of these sentences should I use?

1. Until they **have prepared** our room, we will wait in the hotel lobby.
2. Until they **prepare** our room, we will wait in the hotel lobby.

Or should those be written the other way around?

3. We will wait in the hotel lobby until they **have prepared** our room.
4. We will wait in the hotel lobby until they **prepare** our room.
5. We will wait in the hotel lobby **while** they **prepare** our room.

Comment: That depends on whether you want to move out of the hotel lobby before they have finished preparing the room.

Comment: The order makes no difference except for the emphasis you wish to give the ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [until + perfect present / present](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62627/until-perfect-present-present)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "it's amazing" and "this is amazing"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253446/what-is-the-difference-between-its-amazing-and-this-is-amazing)